# Raster: How to remove top-valued cells such that mean value is reduced by X%?

Tags: raster, r-raster

Say I have a RasterLayer with a mean value of X.

How would I go about iteratively removing the highest-value cells such that I reduce the mean value by some percentage?

The background of my question is I have a spatial layer with cell values that represent relative 'risk'. I want to determine how much is the least area to 'close' (i.e. how many and which of the highest cells to remove) such that overall 'risk' is reduced by 10%, 20%, 50%, etc. I am fiddling with some basic raster operations but I was wondering if anyone had done something similar before and how.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you improve your question? If your question is about how to do this with raster data you ought to show a function that does this for a vector. If you do not know how to do this for a vector, then ask about that instead.

Comment: @RobertHijmans sorry for the unclear question- I am pretty green with R operations. I will try to frame the question like a vector--


If I have a vector of length X and mean Y, how would I go about removing the fewest elements of the vector such that the mean of the new vector is 0.8Y?

I am sorry if that isn't any clearer...

Comment: Then please edit your question, show some simple example data, what you have tried, and what the result should be